# Does serverperfmode work on Apple Silicon Macs?

Tags: startup, performance, server.app, apple-silicon, nvram

Is it possible to enable serverperfmode on an Apple Silicon Mac?

I am using an M1 Mac Mini on macOS 11.2, and following [Apple's instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202528). I enabled `serverperfmode=1` in the NVRAM boot-args, and restarted the machine. However, I'm not seeing any of the values in `sysctl -a`, `ulimit -u`, or `ulimit -n` change.

I have successfully done this on Intel-based Mac Minis in the past. Is it possible that `serverperfmode` is simply not supported on Apple Silicon Macs?

Here are some of the values I'm seeing on this machine, which seem unchanged from before enabling serverperfmode.

```
% nvram boot-args                   
boot-args   serverperfmode=1
% ulimit -n                           
256
% ulimit -u                              
2666
```

Comment: I ran across this article on MacWorld https://www.macworld.com/article/340211/how-to-access-recovery-mode-safe-mode-and-other-boot-modes-on-an-m1-mac.html Scroll down to "No SMC to reset, no NVRAM to zap (mostly)." It seems to indicate that, at the very least, NVRAM has changed substantially, so that command may do nothing. You may need to access developer documentation on apple.com to be sure.